# Calculating average grade using functions and lists in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do is to make a list of names and grades based on user input, and then to show the list as well as to organize the list in a table, and finally to compute the average grade.

So I want my script to prompt the user to input a name and a grade, and then store them in a list. This prompt will be repeated until the user enter an empty string (just press enter while prompted to enter a name).

I have a problem storing the list, and initiating the printing and calculation when empty string is entered.

Here is what I got so far:

```
    #   Importing Python tabulate package
from tabulate import tabulate

#   Defining functions
def getRec():
    #   Get a record from user input, return an empty of the user entered an empty string as input
    name = str(input("Enter a name: "))
    if name != "":
        score = int(input("Enter the grade of " + name +": "))
        return name,score
    else:
        return None

def addList(List,rec):
    #   Add a rec into the list
    List = tuple(rec)
    return List,rec

def putRec(List):
    #   Print a record in a specific format
    print(List)

def printTable(List):
    #   Print a table with a heading
    print(tabulate(List,showindex="always",headers=["Index","Name","Grade"]))

def average(List):
    #   Computes the average score and return the value
    total = List[0][1]
    avg = total/len(List)
    print("Average Grade: ",avg)

#   Main function

List = []
rec = []
while True:
    rec = list(getRec())
    List = addList(List,rec)

    if rec == None:
        for index in range(len(List)):
            print()
            putRec(List)
            print()
            printTable(List)
            print()
            average(List)
        break
```

When I try to initiate the printing and calculation, there's an error because I returned a 'None' on my first function. But if I return zeros, the list became zeros. I need help trying to initiate my other functions and perhaps fixing how I create my list based on the inputs.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether `getRec()` returns None before adding the record to the list :

```
#   Main function

List = []
rec = []
while True:
    result = getRec()
    print(result)

    if result == None:
        for index in range(len(List)):
            print()
            putRec(List)
            print()
            printTable(List)
            print()
            average(List)
        break

    else:
        rec = list(result)
        addList(List,rec)
```

There was also a mistake in your `addList` function. You must use `.append()` method to add an item to a list. No return value is needed then.

```
def addList(List,rec):
    #   Add a rec into the list
    List.append(tuple(rec))
```

The code should run without any issue with these 2 changes, but the average grade will still be wrong. You need to use a for loop to calculate the sum of all grades :

```
def average(List):
    #   Computes the average score and return the value
    total = 0

    for r in List:
        total += r[1]

    avg = total/len(List)
    print("Average Grade: ",avg)
```

Hope it helps :)

EDIT :

Not sure why you used a loop to print the whole table. You just don't need it. Here is the code without a loop :

```
while True:
    result = getRec()
    print(result)

    if result == None:
        print()
        putRec(List)
        print()
        printTable(List)
        print()
        average(List)
        break

    else:
        rec = list(result)
        addList(List,rec)
```

Comment: The code works! Thank you so much for your help. However, the code prints the list, the table, and the average twice.

Comment: You're right! By using the for-loop, I end up printing everything by the number of elements in the list. Thank you for looking out.